# Product attribute on the shop page only for variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using code that shows the product attribute on the shop page.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_loop_product_meta', 50 );
function custom_loop_product_meta() {
    global $product;

    if( ! is_object( $product ) ) { 
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    } 
    
    echo '<div class="pa-style-block">';
    echo esc_html( pll__( 'Sizes' ) );
    echo '<span class="pa-style-text">: ' . $product->get_attribute('pa_size') . '</span>';
    echo '</div>';

}
```

How to properly add the `if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) )` condition so that the attribute is shown only for variable products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following to display your "Size" attribute only for variable products:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_loop_product_meta', 50 );
function custom_loop_product_meta() {
    global $product;

    if( ! is_object($product) ) { 
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    } 
    
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        printf( '<div class="pa-style-block">%s: <span class="pa-style-text">%s</span></div>',
            esc_html( pll__('Sizes') ), $product->get_attribute('pa_size') );
    }
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and help!